# Is a "close" icon necessary in other platforms?

Tags: cocos2d-x

In iOS, one doesn't need to add a close icon for an app. In the rare event that one wants to kill an app they can do it via the OS.

When looking at the cocos2d-x project that is created by default when using the console (v3.1.1), the sample HelloWorld scene places a button on screen to "close" the app.

Is this actually required in ANY platform ? Does it make sense to add this button at all ?

Answer (score 0):

Apple usually rejects on this and Google and Microsoft don't like it.

You can, however, have close buttons on menus or popovers (say, like a pause screen).

Comment: If I don't have it, is there any platform that won't be able to kill the app ?

Comment: Well, you control what platform you release to right? So if you only release to the big three, then no. I have no idea why Cocos2d is there... probably as an example of how to do a button

Comment: There are other menu buttons too, but the code even has specific code pointing out that windows store apps do not implement a "close button". So its just weird that its there.